# VueJS, this.$route.query.page, and Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have been working on this for about 2 hours now, no to avail. I have searched the Internet, tried creating a condition, etc.

So I have a method in a VueJS component that looks like this:

```
paginate() {
  const test = this.$route.query.page;
  console.log(test);
  this.currPage = parseInt(test);
}
```

The word "test" on the last line has a red underline and I get an error message saying this:

> const test: LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]
>
> Argument of type 'LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.Vetur(2345)

How should I solve the TypeScript error without editing the TypeScript configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means `test` can be `null`. Its type is likely `string | null` which is a union type. You need test it to eliminate the `null` case.

For example

```
paginate() {
  const test = this.$route.query.page;
  console.log(test);

  if (typeof test === 'string') {
    // `test` has type string here because of the predicate.
    this.currPage = parseInt(test);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcA3gLABQccAJFBOjMAFylwCO6wUAnqyXDCoA5izgEYUAJYA7YXAA+cGVkxwAvhrgBeNp2582Q0axWY1m9QG5K1HOihQACiOAB+U+gC2AI242qQRFZVCYACgBKUltqOBwIGQk4JiTdGAALKQIAOjoGJmz9XmzjYADYuISCCExgbMwIYTCUmAiAmOopZDhmnjBgCG6WnW1dAHIJaTkxqPJAioB6BbgAAxaVuHTCZL7gcUlZeXTuPb8cDAI9weTjwShgBClzgo7YjKzs+0cXUR0gqEuAEkZDBmsAJG1XuoYtCKOogA)

***Please note that the above solution, while indeed proper, changes the meaning of the original code, leaving `this.currPage` unchanged if `test` is not a string.***